# Why do we prefer a cross over slope of -1 (20 dB/decade) for bode plot of power converters?

Tags: power-supply, switch-mode-power-supply, control-system, stability, bode-plot

The [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fr7WVx1uCxg) mentions (@12:45), we should ensure the slope at cross over should be around -1 (20 dB/decade). He mentions we can apply phase margin test if this condition is satisfied.

As far as I know we can apply phase margin tests for non-minimum phase systems (ie, with no RHP and delay). Is the cross over slope an indication for non-minimum phase systems in any way?

[Another source](https://uomustansiriyah.edu.iq/media/lectures/5/5_2019_02_11!09_58_07_AM.pdf) also mentions similar design condition.

[image]

**Why second order [roll-offs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Roll-off) are not preferred in power supply converter whereas it is preferred in filters?**

Other possible reasons.

1. -20 dB/decade implies simple pole and no need to worry about resonance phenomenon etc
2. -40 dB/decade implies sharp change at phase around crossover frequency which might impact phase margin.
3. Filters are open loop systems and hence no issue of closed loop stability considerations. The moment you close a loop it can cause stability issues in an earlier stable 2nd order system.

[image]
[image]
[Image source](https://eepower.com/technical-articles/biricha-lecture-notes-on-analog-and-digital-power-supply-design-part-2d/)